# CSS : Two image on one html element in IE

Tags: html, css

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Windows (vers 14 February 2006), see www.w3.org">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>
      Hello
    </title>
    <style type="text/css">

        div#myDiv {
                border: 1px solid #bed6f8; 
                background: url(images/image1.gif) no-repeat 5px bottom, #bed6f8 url(images/image2.png) repeat-x; 
                color: #000000; 
                font-weight: bold;
        }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myDiv">
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

FireFox :

[image]

IE:

[image]

code related to menu

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a class="leftCornerRound parent menuheader" id="home" href="#"><span>Item 1</span></a>
            <div>           
            <ul>                
                <li><a class="parent" href="#" id="SubItem1"><span>Sub Item 1</span></a>
                    <div><ul>
                        <li><a class="parent" href="#" id="SubItem1.1"><span>Sub Item 1.1</span></a>
                            <div><ul>
                                <li><a class="ui-widget-header" href="#"><span>Sub Item 1.1.1</span></a></li>
                                <li><a class="ui-widget-header" href="#"><span>Sub Item 1.1.2</span></a></li>
                            </ul></div>
                        </li>
.
.
.
.
```

css related to this:

```
div#menu a.parent {
    border: 1px solid #bed6f8; 
    background: url(images/submenu-pointer-bottom.gif) no-repeat 5px bottom, #bed6f8 url(css/blueSky/images/header.png) repeat-x; 
    color: #000000; 
    font-weight: bold;
}

div#menu a.parent:hover {
    border: 1px solid #bed6f8; 
    background: url(images/submenu-pointer-bottom.gif) no-repeat 5px bottom, #c6deff url(css/blueSky/images/default.png) repeat-x; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    color: #000000; 
}
```

Comment: what's the question please elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend adding another wrapper element, and applying the second background to that.

You already have a wrapper element. You have `li` and `a`.

You should put the `css/blueSky/images/default.png` background on the `li`, and leave the `images/submenu-pointer-bottom.gif` background on the `a`.

Make sure the elements are positioned correctly: the `li`s will need `float: left` and the `a`s will need `display: block`.

---

If you need multiple backgrounds on a single element in IE lower than v9, you could use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/):
http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#pie-background

Comment: actually i want that on my anchor tag of menu item. Any other option for this?

Comment: Your question does not make sense with regards to the information you've provided. Where is the "menu" or "menu items" in your code?

Comment: thanks for the help. Your trick worked for me. Can u post ur comment as ans so can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple backgrounds aren't cross browser supported.

It is only available in >=IE9, for more information have a look at the [compatibility table here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: any other option ?? I want this for my menu. If my menu item contains submenu then i need to show arrow on that.

Comment: @jaychapani Add another `<div>` inside the current `div` and define the second background there. Make them same size, and position and that should fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use 2 divs, using one to hold the first and the other to hold the second image. this way it should not be a problem in IE nor firefox.

```
    <div id="myDiv">
      <div id="secondDiv">
        <br />
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: actually i want that on my anchor tag of menu item :(

Comment: Ah i suppose that would be a problem indeed.. next time try to put in an example with the anchor tag, so we can give you a solution that helps right away :)